# Как передать переменную?

Tags: joomla

Доброго времени суток! Пишу свой компонент для joomla 1.7  и столкнулся с такой проблемой:  в шаблоне вида (default.php) есть форма, при нажатии на кнопку submit происходит переход в контроллер (entry.php). Так вот, если поля формы не заполнены, я создаю массив, с сообщениями об ошибках ($errors) - вопрос, как мне передать $errors обратно в default.php? 
Я пока придумал только через сессию, но этот вариант не подходит.

Comment: Думаю стоит прочитать сначала что такое ajax

Comment: ajax я немного знаю - просто нет мыслей, как это реализовать

Comment: ну так передавай данные формы через post, при ошибке тоже через post возвращай что не так и скриптом оповещай пользователя

Answer (score 1):

Есть механизм Joomla, который при редиректе передаёт сообщение для следующего вызова view. Реализован он через ту же сессию. Поэтому и с массивом — сделайте через сессию. Чем плохо?

Comment: плохо тем, что эти ошибки так и будут висеть, пока пользователь не введет все правильно. а я хочу, что-бы при перезагрузке страницы они исчезали

Comment: Так надо при прочтении - прожевать и съесть : ) Тогда покажется лишь раз.

Answer (score 1):

Логика действий не совсем правильная - обработчики форм корректно было бы установить на той же странице, откуда отправляется форма. После того, как вы проверите входные данные - передайте результат другой странице(на которую необходимо переадресовать - в вашем случае `entry.php`).

default.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['submit'])){
    /* проверка полей */
    if(empty($error)){
        header("Location: entry.php");
    }
}
foreach($errors as $error){
    echo $error;
}
?>

<form action='' method='POST'>
    ...
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: это противоречит логике joomla (MVC)

Comment: @woland, Что мешает вам закинуть 1 часть в контроллер, другую в представление?